# How to stop a thread that sleeps in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have several threads, some of them are waiting, and some are running normally. One of them waits for a certain amount of time and then does something, in a loop, forever. What I have to do is, if a thread is sleeping, stop it, if a thread is not sleeping, wait for it to finish. My idea was to iterate through all threads and do something like this:

```
    for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) 
    {  
        if (t.getState() == Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING && t != Thread.currentThread()) 
        t.interrupt();
    } 

    for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) 
    {       
        if (t != Thread.currentThread())
        t.join();
    }
```

But what happens to the one thread that waits for a certain amount of time and then runs again, in a loop. If it is sleeping in the moment I iterate over it, it should stop, but what if it is running at that moment, and then i wait for it to finish, will it ever finish? Ideally i want her cycle to finish and then stop her, but I am confused as how i could achieve that and what will my current code do.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: @shmosel So I should check at the end of the cycle if it is interrupted?

Comment: That's right. Note that the InterruptedException clears the interrupt flag, so you'll need to return directly or reset the flag.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but bear in mind that the JVM Thread scheduler primary responsibility is to decide which thread should run and also when to move a thread out of running state etc. There is no guarantee that the Thread Scheduler chooses a particular thread to run, you can only influence this behaviour using methods like sleep(), yield(), join() and setPriority() from Thread class, and also by using methods like wait(), notify() and notifyAll() from Object class.

So you may end up stopping threads or waiting based on the pseudo-random choice on the scheduler.

If you wish to stop a process gently, there are other ways to achieve that.